# Calculation in script and send result to a cell of active row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

[image: stock/average]

The "stock/average" sheet calculates the average purchase price. F is Products and H is the purchase price.

[image: Sale]

I need to calculate and save profit/loss of each sale in the E column after every sale. Like: the purchase price of the first product is 14200 (First image # stock/average, column H, second product) so 2800 should be put here. I can do it using vlookup or query but the purchase price gets changed with each purchase so I need to do it using the script and preserve the result.

[Link to Spreadsheet:](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zEHjZ08ooksyWLx95MmXjIvaSbgzMgLeFH6GuoM6eas/edit?usp=sharing)

Please help.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zEHjZ08ooksyWLx95MmXjIvaSbgzMgLeFH6GuoM6eas/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you already read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets? If not, do it and add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in this answer is presented in two parts:

**Section One** - Add this to your IF statement.

---

```
var thissheet = range.getSheet();
var edditedCol = range.columnStart;
var edittedRow = range.rowStart;
var productdetails = sheet.getRange(edittedRow,1,1,5).getValues();
var product = productdetails[0][0];
var qty = productdetails[0][1];
var sellprice = productdetails[0][2];
// Logger.log("DEBUG: product =  "+product+", qty:"+qty+", sellprice="+sellprice);
var avg = getcost(product);
var net = +sellprice-(+avg*qty);
var netprofit = Math.round(net * 100) / 100
sheet.getRange(edittedRow,5).setValue(netprofit);
// Logger.log("DEBUG: net profit = "+netprofit);
```

This identifies the edited row and column, and get the values for the appropriate
  - Product
    - Qty
    - Total sales value
  - calls a separate function to return the average cost for the relevant product, 
    - calculates the net profit,
  - updates the value in the "Profit" Column on the sheet.

---

**Section Two** - a sub-routine gets the average cost from the "stock/average" Sheet.

---

```
function getcost(product){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheetname = "stock/average";
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
    var Fvals = sheet.getRange("F5:F").getValues();
    var Flast = Fvals.filter(String).length;
    var sarange = sheet.getRange(5,6,Flast,7);
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: sarange = "+sarange.getA1Notation());
    var data = sarange.getValues();
    // convert the 2D array to a 1D array for the "Product" column.
    var colA = new Array()
    for(i=0;i<data.length;++i){
        colA.push(data[i][0]) ;// taking index 0 means I'll get column A of each row and put it in the new array
    }
    // find the posityion of the editted product on the "stack/average" sheet
    var pos = colA.indexOf(product);
    // get the average cost for this line.
    var avgcost = data[pos][2];
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the average cost = "+avgcost);

    return avgcost;
}
```

Comment: It is working perfectly. Thanks a lot, man. I was really in need of it.